# No splash screen after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: display, nvidia

Elementary OS splash screen has dissapeared after installing nvidia drivers, is there an easy way to restore it? I´ve read some tutorials for Ubuntu but they're hard to follow and results weren't guaranteed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.**

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at login screen to open the root terminal
there you use

`apt purge nvidia` to remove the nvidia driver and go back to the noveau driver. after that `reboot`

**Step 2.**

To install the current stable version of the nvidia driver by writing the current commands in either the root terminal or

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers` to add the driver repository to the list

`sudo apt-get update` to update your repository list making the repository active

After that use `sudo apt-get install nvidia-387` to get the latest driver.

If that doesn't work redo step 1.